# Not exact format of dots in doc. document list after formating it to html via LibreOffice

Tags: formatting, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When I format my doc document into html file via LibreOffice, I'm getting a black dots instead of the valid one's.

**Example doc. document list before formatting:**
[doc document before saving as html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZZ0e.png)

**After saving as html page via LibreOffice:**
[After saving as html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuJU9.png)

Is there any plugin for LibreOffice to make the marking exactly the same or is there any other way to make it look exactly the same after formatting?

Comment: Sorry for links to the images as I'm not allowed to post embedded images as soon as I do not have 10 reputation points

Comment: Regarding the version of the LibreOffice, I'm using the LibreOffice 6.4.6.2